# indexing data types with numbers that start with 0 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I have a function that will convert 3 numbers into a date.

```
def conv(month, day, year):
    months = ('None','January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December')
    print(months[month],str(day)+',',year)
```

so if I run the function like this: conv(6,17,2016)
the output will be:

```
June 17, 2016
```

so far so good, but what if I give 06 for the month instead of 6 how can I get the same output like above? is there any way to use 06 and somehow turning it into 6 for indexing or I have to only give 6 and there is no way for doing that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `datetime` module? It has the facility to deal with zero-padded values, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: 06 would be invalid - it'd throw an error

Comment: yeah I know I can use datetime but I just wondering if there is a way for that indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are aware that 06 will automatically raise a syntax error, that means you can only create a string such as `"06"`.

with that said, simple use to convert to `int`

```
number = int(month)
```

Comment: yeah you are right I have to either give the 6 or give 06 as a string

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `datetime`,

```
In [31]: d = datetime.datetime.now().date()

In [32]: d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
Out[32]: 'August 30, 2018'
```

Or use `calender`.

```
import calendar
def conv(month, day, year):
    print(calendar.month_name[int(month)],str(day)+',',year)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little easier to digest:

```
import datetime

def conv(month, day, year):
    d = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    print(d.strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

cast your 06 to `int` - it will then be a normal 6. So you will print by using `print(months[int(month)],str(day)+',',year)`

but as mentioned in the comments - just use `datetime` module instead :-)

Comment: `def conv(int(month), day, year):` is invalid syntax

Comment: you sure? well, then it can be specified later in the code by doing `print(months[int(month)],str(day)+',',year)`

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I tested it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert tuple to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) then use [`.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format it:

```
>>> tup=(2018,8,30)
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(*tup)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 30, 0, 0)
>>> print(datetime(*tup)) # print
2018-08-30 00:00:00
>>> datetime(*tup).strftime('%B %d, %y')
'August 30, 18'
>>>
```